# Port forwarding to another network adapter

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have two network adapters which are wireless and cable network. I want to use wireless network for Skype, torrent, MSN or something not related with jobs but I want to use cable network for RDP, software development, SQL connection.

İs there any way to redirecting programs to another network connection?

Comment: Using which operating system? (Also, I think this is called "policy routing"; port forwarding is about incoming connections.)

Comment: My OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to organise routing based on applications that make connections, but fairly easy by IP address if you can work out a routing scheme that has a default for non-work items, and then specific routes for work related destinations.

So in the scenario you describe, you want your wireless to do most things, and happens to be the types of activities that you could write specific routes for, so this should be the default route.  Accept the IP address and default route from the wifi connection.

The cable is to be used for specific things, such as

1. rdp
2. sql connection
3. software development

Normally these types of activities are to specific and known servers.  All you need is their IP addresses, and you can route requests to these servers via the cable connection.

If you have to get an IP by dhcp for the cable connection, you'll need to delete the default route they provide you:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <cable next hop>
```

Then add specific routes for the servers you want to connect to via cable:

```
route add <rdp server ip> mask 255.255.255.255 <cable next hop>
route add <sql server ip> mask 255.255.255.255 <cable next hop>
route add <dev server ip> mask 255.255.255.255 <cable next hop>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wrote an entry with your answer: http://sanirimbuyok.blogspot.com/2011/12/ag-bagdastrcs-secmek.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows haven't at all **source** policy routing, only target (using `route add`). Can't recall exact recipe for Tux, but *it can do it*